# Line chart data points for Google combo chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I am working with Google combo Chart

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function drawVisualization() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Month', 'Madagascar', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
              ['2004/05', 165, 938, 614.6],
              ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 682],
              ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 623],
              ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 609.4],
              ['2008/09', 1026, 366, 569.6]
            ]);

            var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            ac.draw(data, {
                title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                vAxis: { title: "Cups" },
                hAxis: { title: "Month" },
                seriesType: "bars",
                series: { 2: { type: "line", curveType: "function", pointSize: 8 } }
            });            

        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now it creates the Google Combo Chart correctly but my requirement is that the line chart must have it's each data point to be in middle of each blue bar column, instead of at the left upper corner of the red bar column. To see this, please copy and paste the above code in a html page and see this page in browser.